# WHERE clause with INSERT statement, "Incorrect Syntax" at the WHERE, and IF NOT EXISTS running regardless of if record exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause, sql-insert

I have this INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO Appointments (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate) 
VALUES (1, 11, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()))
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM Appointments 
     WHERE StaffID = 1 AND CustomerID = 11 AND TimeSlot = 1 AND AppDate = DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()));
```

Yet it says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'"

This is very basic error, but have no clue whats up.

I have also tried using IF NOT EXISTS, which gives no syntax errors, but also doesn't work, preforming the insert even though the record with the values does already exist:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM Appointments 
        WHERE StaffID = 1 AND CustomerID = 11 AND TimeSlot = 1 AND AppDate = DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Appointments (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate) 
        VALUES (1, 11, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()))
END;
```

The record with the values 1, 11, 1, and tomorrow does 100% already exist, yet inserts it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify any `WHERE` clause with the `INSERT .. VALUES` statement. But you can do that with the `INSERT .. SELECT` statement as shown below.

Also...

> The record with the values 1, 11, 1, and tomorrow does 100% already exist, yet inserts it again.

`GETDATE()` returns a timestamp with fractional seconds precision, which is unlikely to already exist in your table. You probably want to use the `DATE` data type, e.g. using

```
DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

#### INSERT .. SELECT

```
INSERT INTO Appointments (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate) 
SELECT 1, 11, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM Appointments 
  WHERE StaffID = 1 
    AND CustomerID = 11 
    AND TimeSlot = 1 
    AND AppDate = DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
);
```

#### INSERT .. SELECT with common table expression to avoid duplication

Or perhaps, avoiding calculating `GETDATE()` several times:

```
WITH ins (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate)
  AS (SELECT 1, 11, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
INSERT INTO Appointments (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate) 
SELECT ins.StaffID, ins.CustomerID, ins.TimeSlot, ins.AppDate
FROM ins
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM Appointments 
  WHERE StaffID = ins.StaffID 
    AND CustomerID = ins.CustomerID
    AND TimeSlot = ins.TimeSlot 
    AND AppDate = ins.AppDate
);
```

#### INSERT .. SELECT with set operations

Or, again, more concisely using set operations:

```
INSERT INTO Appointments (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate)
SELECT 1, 11, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
EXCEPT
SELECT StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate
FROM Appointments
```

#### MERGE

Actually, the whole "insert if not exists" concept can be modelled using [`MERGE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(v=sql.105).aspx) as well:

```
MERGE INTO Appointments a
USING (
  SELECT 
    1 StaffID, 
    11 CustomerID,
    1 TimeSlot,
    DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AppDate
) ins
ON (
  a.StaffID = ins.StaffID AND 
  a.CustomerID = ins.CustomerID AND 
  a.TimeSlot = ins.TimeSlot AND 
  a.AppDate = ins.AppDate
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate)
  VALUES (ins.StaffID, ins.CustomerID, ins.TimeSlot, ins.AppDate)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for an amazing answer, I've only implemented your 2nd variation, as I need to have multiple clauses within the where, and I'm unsure how do implement them in your other examples. 

I might submit it as a separate question also as it involves the 4 fields in this example, but needs to check for 3 variations (time+customer+date - time+staff+date - staff+time+customer+date) I feel there must be a simpler way than 3 long separate checks

Comment: @Tom: Sure, feel free to ask another question - and link to it from here.

Comment: Oh, no need, it just required an OR, I was over thinking things.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't involve time while insertion and write a query as:

```
INSERT INTO Appointments (StaffID, CustomerID, TimeSlot, AppDate) 
select 1, 11, 1, DATEADD(day, 1, cast(GETDATE() as date))
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * 
 FROM Appointments 
 WHERE StaffID = 1 AND CustomerID = 11 AND TimeSlot = 1 
 AND AppDate = DATEADD(day, 1, cast(GETDATE() as date))
 )
```

Comment: I have the "AppDate" as just a Date type in my database and realised soon after posting this that that was causing the "IF NOT EXIST" to fail. :)